# Word is selected in RichTextBox and Right-clicked then shown in ContextMenu C#

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, spell-checking

Programmer, Master.

Please help me... Let me learn by your example.

Description :
The word are shown in a popup when a word is selected and right-clicked.
For example,
INPUT : "Barcelona is my favorite football club".

After I selected the word "**football**", then the right-clicked and the word are shown in a popup menu "This is **football**".

When I clicked those word in popup menu, it will replace the word in INPUT
with the word in pop up menu, like this example.

OUTPUT : Barcelona is my favorite **This is football** club."

Please.. help me.

I'm really blind of ContextMenu..

Here is the code :

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
private EventHandler menuHandler;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    menuHandler = new System.EventHandler(this.Menu_Click);// what's menu_click?
}

private void Menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 12);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

    richTextBox1.SelectedText = ((MenuItem)sender).Text;
}

private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
      {
         Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
         int index = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(point);
         textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(index);

         int length = 1;

         if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text[index]))
         {
             while (index > 0 && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text[index - 1]))
             { index--; length++; }

              while (index + length < richTextBox1.Text.Length &&
                  !Char.IsWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text[index + length]) &&
                  (!Char.IsPunctuation(richTextBox1.Text[index + length]) ||
                  richTextBox1.Text[index + length] == Char.Parse("'"))
              ) length++;

              richTextBox1.SelectionStart = index;
              richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;
              contextMenu.MenuItems.Clear(); // error here
              contextMenu.MenuItems.Add("This is "+richTextBox1.SelectedText, menuHandler); //error here
              //What's next Sir?
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

//next..., I'm really don't know.

It doesn't work. Please help :) :) :)

Comment: what error you got and where you declared contextMenu

Comment: Sir, contextMenu1 doesn't show. "I contextMenu1.Show(richTextBox1, point);" after contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(".....").

Any suggestion Sir?

Comment: richTextBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu ; in Form1() ?

Comment: is it run success fully are showing any compilation error?

Comment: @IOIO MAD : REally Nice, richTextBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu, It works. haha. I should have thought that. :)

Civa, thanks, it run successfully :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to show the contextMenu  add

```
richTextBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu ;
```

to rhe initalization or in Form1()

Answer (score 0):

u just use bellow thing to show menu

```
contextMenu1.Show(richTextBox1, point);
```